# Beautification and simplification

Tags: discussion

I would like to submit a working code snippet to ask for feedback on how to simplify and/or make the code more readable. Is there a tag or method for this?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Such questions may likely get closed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no tag for this, but an entire site: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Their [tagline](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) matches your request perfectly:

> We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.

Before asking your question, make sure to read their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure your question is well-received.

Comment: Something I use quite often: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5468/3-questions-in-stack-overflow-comments-pointing-to-code-review